# Given $x=x(t)$, $\ddot x = f(x)$ can you find $\dot x(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $x=x(t)$,  $\ddot x = f(x)$ can you find $\dot x(x)$?

In this particular problem I have $\ddot x=-\frac 1{x^{2}}$ and I want to find $\dot x (x)$, is this possible? How about the general case (the one above)?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\dot x=p$. Then
$$
\ddot x=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{dp}{dx}\,p.
$$
The equation becomes
$$
p\,\frac{dp}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}\implies p\,dp=-\frac{dx}{x^2}.
$$
Integrating we get
$$
\frac12\,p^2=\frac1x+C\implies\dot x=\pm\sqrt{\frac2x+C\,}\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Just curious: If I wanted to do this with definite integrals, what would be the limits of integrations after the $p\,dp=-\frac {dx}{x^2}$ part?

Comment: If $p(x_0)=p_0$, it would be $\int_{p_0}^pp\,dp=-\int_{x_0}^x\dfrac{dx}{x^2}$.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to put the same limits in both sides? As in $\int _{x_0}^x p\, dp = - \int_{x_0}^x \frac {dx}{x^2}$?

Comment: @user14141414 In the above comment, the LHS is with respect to $p$. So as the RHS ranges from $x_0$ to $x$, the LHS ranges from $p_0=p(x_0)$ to $p=p(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Julian beat me to it, but here's an answer for your particular $\ddot{x}$. Rewrite the differential equation in terms of $\dot{x}$.

$$\ddot{x} = \frac{d\dot{x}}{dt} = -\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Now divide both sides by $\dot{x}$.

$$\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}=-\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{1}{\dot{x}}$$

This simplifies to a nice, separable equation:

$$\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{1}{\dot{x}}$$

$$\int\dot{x}\ d\dot{x}=-\int\frac{1}{x^2} dx$$

$$\frac12\dot{x}^2=\frac{1}{x} +C$$

$$\dot{x}^2=\sqrt{\frac{2}{x} +C}$$